# Method to add ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Let's say I have a button called button1. If I want to create an actionListener for the button which method should I choose: (In the second one, you have to extend actionListener interface)

```
// Imports
public class Test{
    JButton test = new JButton();
    Test(){
        // Pretend there is an adapter
        test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                ...
            }
        });
    ...
}
```

or

```
// Imports
public class Test2 extends ActionListener{
    JButton button2 = new JButton();
    Test2(){
        button2.addActionListener(this);
    }
    // Pretend there is an adapter

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == button2){
            ...
        }else{
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, you have to *implement* the `ActionListener` interface. Other than that, the answer is "it depends". If it makes sense to reuse the same action listener for several graphical components, then use the second version. If handling the event is a one-shot affair for a single component, then use the first version.

Answer (score 3):

Go for the first. You shouldn't have your GUI classes also implementing your listeners as this is asking the GUI or view class to do too much. By separating out your listener code, even if it's in an anonymous listener class, you'll have an easier time later should you want to completely separate your listener code from your view code.

Comment: +1 for not making your UI classes implement the listener interfaces as well

Answer (score 1):

If every listener is unique, you'll probably want to use the anonymous classes (first example). If you would otherwise have to rewrite the same code over and over again, then implementing it in a named class (as in your second example) would be preferable so you can just reuse the same listener.

However, rather than extending ActionListener (as in your second example), you'll probably find that putting the listener implementation into a different class (even an inner class which implements ActionListener) provides better logical logical separation of your code.